# How to pass definitions to \AtBeginDocument?

Tags: programming, babel, code, font-encodings

I need to delay execution of a chuk of code to the time when other packages are loaded so I wrap it into `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\reserved@a#1#2{%
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \edef\reserved@c{#2}%
    \ifx\reserved@b\reserved@c
      \let\cyrillicencoding\reserved@c
    \fi}
  \def\cdp@elt#1#2#3#4{%
    \reserved@a{#1}{OT2}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{LCY}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{X2}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2C}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2B}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2A}%
    \if@uni@code
      \reserved@a{#1}{EU1}%
      \reserved@a{#1}{EU2}%
    \fi}
  \cdp@list
}
```

This code looks at the list of loaded font encodings (saved in `\cdp@list`), compare it with predefined list of desired Cyrillic encodings ordered from least preferable to the  most preferable (OT2, LCY... EU2) and save the name of selected encoding to the macro `\cyrillicencoding`. Boolean macro `\if@uni@code` is evaluated to true if either LuaTeX or XeTeX is running:

```
\newif\if@uni@code
\ifdefined\luatexversion \@uni@codetrue \else
\ifdefined\XeTeXrevision \@uni@codetrue \fi\fi
```

It works fine. However it fails if I move some portion of preparatory definitions out of the box. For example,

```
\def\reserved@a#1#2{%
  \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
  . . .
\fi}
\AtBeginDocument{\cdp@list}
```

I guess that macros within moving argument of `\AtBeginDocument` should be somehow `protect`ed or `expendafter`. **Can someone elucidate where my troubles come from**? And second question: **Is it good practice to delay big chunks of code to at the begin document time?**

**UPDATE:** here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mytest}
\usepackage[T2B]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\verb|cyrillicencoding|={\csname cyrillicencoding\endcsname}
\end{document}
```

and `mytest.sty`

```
\def\reserved@a#1#2{%
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \edef\reserved@c{#2}%
    \ifx\reserved@b\reserved@c
      \let\cyrillicencoding\reserved@c
    \fi}
\def\cdp@elt#1#2#3#4{%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2C}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2B}%
    \reserved@a{#1}{T2A}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\cdp@list}
```

If the entire content of `mytest.sty` would be wrapped into `\AtBeginDocument`, output will be `\cyrillicencoding=T2B`.

Comment: Please give a minimal example showing the 'does not work' behaviour.

Comment: That does not seem to be a minimal example to me. Where does `\cdp@list` come from? Also, you seem to be defining `\resereved@a` and expecting it not to change. The `\reserved@...` macros are _kernel only_, and you should in general really know what you are doing before you make use of one of them.

Comment: @Josef, this code is initially borrowed from `russianb.ldf` from official babel distribution; \cdp@list is defined elsewhere, I guess that this is NFSS macro as it expands to something like {encoding}{family}{series}{shape} (4 args of `\cdp@elt#1#2#3#4`).

Comment: @Igor: The `minimal` class is just a minimal form of a class and not intended to be used for minimal working examples, even if the name makes it look like it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should *never* rely on the meaning of `\reserved@a` and similar control sequence names that the kernel uses quite often as "scratch macros". So taking out the definition of `\reserved@a` from `\AtBeginDocument` is wrong and this is why the version with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\cdp@list}
```

For example, with a minimal document, the meaning of `\reserved@a` that I get when `\@begindocumenthook` is executed is

```
> \reserved@a=macro:
->\def \@currenvir {document}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line }\csname document\endcsname .
```

There's nothing wrong in having big chunks of code in `\AtBeginDocument`; however you can shorten the token list by saying

```
\def\@setcyrillicencoding{%
  \def\sce@a##1##2{%
    \edef\sce@b{##1}%
    \edef\sce@c{##2}%
    \ifx\sce@b\sce@c
      \let\cyrillicencoding\sce@c
    \fi}%
  \def\cdp@elt##1##2##3##4{%
    \sce@a{##1}{OT2}%
    \sce@a{##1}{LCY}%
    \sce@a{##1}{X2}%
    \sce@a{##1}{T2C}%
    \sce@a{##1}{T2B}%
    \sce@a{##1}{T2A}%
    \if@uni@code
      \sce@a{##1}{EU1}%
      \sce@a{##1}{EU2}%
    \fi}%
  \cdp@list
}
\AtBeginDocument{\@setcyrillicencoding}
\@onlypreamble\@setcyrillicencoding
\@onlypreamble\sce@a
\@onlypreamble\sce@b
\@onlypreamble\sce@c
```

The last lines are to free the memory occupied by the macros `\@setcyrillicencoding` and `\sce@x` that are useless in the document. The contents of `\@begindocumenthook` is cleared automatically.

Since `\reserved@a` is used there, it's not recommendable to redefine it.

Answer (score 10):

> Can someone elucidate where my troubles come from?

You are using *reserved* *temporary* macros and then don't use them directly. As soon any other LaTeX kernel macro is executed this macros might be overwritten.
In other words your definitions won't survive until the `\begin{document}` and your `\cdp@list` macros then uses some arbitrary definitions of the temporary macros.

You should use other temporary macros. Should the `babel` code your are calling really require `\reserved@a` to be used, you need to make sure that you make your definitions direct before the usage of the `\cdp@list` macro.

Also your definition of `\cdp@elt` is changed by `fontenc`, so of course you would need to do this definition direct before you are going to use it, not inside your package.

> Is it good practice to delay big chunks of code to at the begin document time?

I would define everything into one macro and add this macro to the hook only. Every time a hook gets more code all of the old code is copied, which is costly if a lot of packages installed a lot of code. Note that you need to double all `#` if you place macro definitions into a macro.

Comment: Minor comment. Maing idea of delaying code here is exactly to allow for `fontenc` to change `\cdp@elt` as `babel` need complete list of encodings loaded throught preamble, both before and after `babel`.